# Unresolved reference: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES

Tags: android, permissions

I started targeting Android 13 with API 33. The app is requesting `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for the older APIs. Now I know that I have to request the new permissions: `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` and `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`.
I have added in the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

and now, as a result, in the setting of the permissions for the app I see an extra option to enable these permissions.
What I can't do is to ask the permission at runtime
If I try to access `Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` in the code I get `unresolved reference` so I can't dynamically request the permission and if I don't then the user needs to do it manually.

How to handle the `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` and `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`?

Comment: Set your compile version in build gradle on 33. If you already have that then update some implementation's.

Comment: I'm doing it already

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem, also compiling and targeting 33

Comment: Nevermind, it was just me changing to compile against api 33 in the wrong gradle file. :/

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall the app after changing the `targetSdk` to get the runtime permission prompt displayed, even though I had denied the old permission. Note: I didn't have "Unresolved reference", just the permission prompt problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions, you should ask permission in runtime.
Also notice:

> Note: If your app only needs to access images, photos, and videos, consider using the photo picker instead of declaring the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions.

Comment: That's the problem. I didn't manage to ask the permission at runtimt because the constants are unresolved even if I'm targeting API 33

Comment: import android.Manifest

Comment: `import android.Manifest` made the difference :·)